# PasteSpecial method of Range class failed when trying to paste into an added ListRow

Tags: excel

I want to copy/paste w transpose data A1:A61 from the active worksheet into columns 2 "B" through 62 "BJ" of the "Client Info" worksheet which contains a formatted table. I search for client name & phone in column 68 "BP" of the "ClientInfoTable". If found, that's the row I want to update, otherwise add a new row and paste into it. The PasteSpecial works fine when updating a FOUND record, but FAILS ONLY when trying to PasteSpecial into an added row. Error: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

```
Sub SaveToMaster(clientfirstname as String, clientlastname as String, clientphone as String)

    Dim addedrow As ListRow
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim clientnamephone As String
    Dim foundcell As Range
    Dim updaterow As Long

    clientnamephone = clientfirstname & " " & clientlastname & " " & clientphone
    
    Range("A1:A61").Copy
    Worksheets("Client Info").Activate
    
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ClientInfoTable")

    Set foundcell = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(68).Find(What:=clientnamephone, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If foundcell Is Nothing Then
        Set addedrow = tbl.ListRows.ADD
        updaterow = addedrow.Index
    Else
        updaterow = tbl.ListRows(foundcell.Row - tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row).Index
    End If
    
    tbl.DataBodyRange(updaterow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why: when you add a ListRow, it apparently clears the copied range. I corrected it by going back to the source workbook (after adding the listrow) and copying the source range.